# Inserting data to mysql via dropdownlist

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my database I have an attribute called lost&found which is either lost or found. in html i made a dropdownlist which shows on lost or found and the user gets to pick one.
how should i return it to my database as lost or found. should i use it as int 0/1 or is there any other solution?

Comment: It's up to you, but TINYINT seems like a good one to me

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a field in your database for "lost" (TINYINT) and set it to either 0 or 1.

An alternative is to have a "lostandfound" field with ENUM("Lost", "Found") and set that accordingly. I'd go for the 0/1 field personally as it's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a database field: lost type: Boolean

if the value of the lost SELECTfield (html) equals true save lost as true else save as false...

if you want to show all lost records use query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE lost = true;
```

if you want to show all found records use query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE lost = false;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the equality

Comment: the equality isn't put in the code it's for the logic with equals true I meant if the selectfield value IS "lost" (aka equals true if the table is lost xD) sorry for the mis-understanding. and if you are talking about the queries I believe you do need them.

Comment: You don't need it. See below (or nearby)

Comment: I am just adding a newby-friendly example for the user it's not that this is the only possibility or the best posibility but great for starters....

Comment: No I get you. it is possible without the =true or =false but my opinion I rather use it xD

Answer (score 0):

@mikem...

```
 CREATE TABLE my_bool(i BOOLEAN NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO my_bool VALUES (1),(0);

 SELECT * FROM my_bool WHERE i;
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 1 |
 +---+

 SELECT * FROM my_bool WHERE NOT i;
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 0 |
 +---+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql>
```